# Learning curves, what to plot exactly?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization

Suppose I have a regularized loss function $$L = Error_{data} + Error_{regulariztion}$$
I want to plot learning curves for training and test set. What should I exactly plot for both training and test sets? the regularized loss $L$ or just the data error $Error_{data}$?